# sql to dplyr - nested select statements

Tags: sql, r, dplyr

I am trying to translate sql to R using the `dplyr` library, which I am new to.

How would I do it for the following SQL?

```
select v1, v2, max(v2) as v3 
from (select v1, v2 
 from data1
 where v1<10)
group by v1, v2;
```

Comment: This query seems to be incorrect? Is it working?

Comment: Is the query executing properly?

Comment: @JimMacaulay It should work now

Comment: Still its an incorrect query, have you executed and tested?

Comment: The way you have it now, with max(v2) grouped by v2 will just be v2. Might as well be `select distinct v1, v2, v2 as v3 from data1 where v1 < 10`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
data1 %>% 
  filter(v1<10) %>% 
  group_by(v1,v2) %>% 
  summarize(v3 = max(v2)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```